# In App Purchase - when trying to buy consumable product again - this in-app purchase has already been bought

Tags: ios, swift, skproduct

I have consumable In-App-Purchase product in my iTunes connect, and when I'm trying to buy it twice (on my iPhone), it tells me that I already bought it. But this is the whole point of consumables, that users can buy them over and over. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: @ravisendhav The accepted answer worked for me

Comment: but it's not working for me.

Please see my code below.

Comment: Did you see this messages in console log:
print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

Comment: how can we clear pending transactions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This happens if you haven't marked the transaction for the original purchase as finished, which you should do in your `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray*)transactions` method after you've successfully processed the purchase.

The method you need to call is `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]`.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. In order to clear previously unfinished transactions one has to run this code once: `let queue = SKPaymentQueue.default();
        queue.transactions.forEach { queue.finishTransaction($0) } `

Answer (score -2):

```
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case .purchased:
            complete(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .failed:
            fail(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .restored:
            restore(transaction: transaction)
            break
        case .deferred:
            break
        case .purchasing:
            break
        }
    }
}
```