# How to sell credit with In App Purchase on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I need to sell credit through my iOS app that offers a service.
The users should be able to buy credit in different amounts (5€, 20€...), this credit will be used for the service that I deliver according to the time of usage.

Should I configure consumable items for each amount? I already know that I should manage the balance server side.

Thanks

**Edit**

Since consumable items is the way, this is how I buy credit:

```
SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:product];
payment.quantity = 1;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

The purchase is successful but I cannot buy the same item(amount) multiple times.
I've also selected: Cleared for Sale **Yes**

Comment: Sounds like you've got the right idea, have you tried it?

Comment: Not yet, just wanted to know if there is a more straightforward way to manage virtual credit.

Comment: The method you have described is the way I built a game previously, different consumables for different amounts of in app currency.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I started implementing this solution, at the moment there is just one thing it's not clear: how can I buy the same amount multiple times? I presume I should mark the item as consumed in the moment I update the balance.

Comment: You don't need to do anything "Consumables are In-App Purchases that must be purchased each time the user needs that item." You only need to be careful that you update the balance successfully and the user does not loose credit to a loss of internet connection - [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf)

Comment: The users will never loose the credit because it's updated to the server after they buy it. But if I try to buy other credit of the same amount (4.99€) I see the message 'This In-App purchase has already been bought.' 'It will be restored for free.'

Comment: Then it sounds like you are currently using 'Non-Consumables' not 'Consumables' - Go and make some new Consumables in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Just checked on iTunes connect, the type is consumable.

Comment: Doesn't sound right, you're gunna have to consult the documentation.

Comment: It looks like I have to do something [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937195/xcode-in-app-purchased-when-trying-to-buy-consumable-product-again-this-in

Comment: There you go, looks like you've answered your own question, probably a good idea to write down your solution as an answer here incase anyone else finds it.

Answer (score 0):

Like explained here:

[XCODE - In App Purchased - When trying to buy Consumable product again - This in-app purchaes has already been bought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937195/xcode-in-app-purchased-when-trying-to-buy-consumable-product-again-this-in)

we need to mark the transaction (I did it in  the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased case):

```
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

and we can buy the item multiple times.