# "You're all set" alert not showing when a purchase is done a second time

Tags: swiftui, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm adding in-app purchase in my app using the new ProductView.
The first time I tried to purchase my product, I got an alert saying "You're all set".
But when I purchased my product a second time, the alert did not show up.
The product is a consumable.
Why is that alert not showing? What am I missing?

```swift
ProductView(id: productId)
    .productViewStyle(.compact)
    .onInAppPurchaseStart { product in
        logger.log("User has started buying \(product.id)")
    }
    .onInAppPurchaseCompletion { product, result in
        if case .success(.success(let transaction)) = result {
            logger.log("Success")
        } else {
            logger.log("Failure")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are any of your logs being called the second time?

Comment: Yes, I have a "Success" message. It's like everything went through, but just the fact that I've already bought the product, the alert won't show up.

Comment: How long did you wait between purchases?
Either way, given that the message is controlled by the OS, I doubt there's much you can do about this.

Comment: I've just waited 15 minutes, still the same

Comment: Are you [calling `finishTransaction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937292/1032372) anywhere? Not sure if that applies to `ProductView` though.

Comment: Good example here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseresult

Comment: I did not, but I'm not sure I should as I think `onInAppPurchaseCompletion` is called only if the purchase is completed. But I see your point, I'll see if there is something similar in this context.

Comment: There's still the potential that you need to do things on your end to complete the transaction after the purchase is complete. So I do think you probably need to call `finish`.

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow "works" in a way that every time I purchase the same product, the transaction actually completes and I get the expected "You're all set" acknowledgment alert message:

```swift
ProductView(id: productId)
    .productViewStyle(.compact)
    .onInAppPurchaseStart { product in
        logger.log("User has started buying \(product.id)")
    }
    .onInAppPurchaseCompletion { product, result in
        switch result {

        case .success(let purchaseResult):
            switch purchaseResult {
            case .success(let verificationResult):
                switch verificationResult {
                case .verified(let transaction):
                    // Do something
                    await transaction.finish()
                case .unverified(let transaction, let verificationError):
                    // Do something
                }
            case .pending:
                // Do something
            case .userCancelled:
                // Do something
            @unknown default:
                // Do something
                break
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

The different placeholders need to be replaced with actual code.

Answer (score 0):

After the purchase is successful you still need to call [`finish`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseresult) on the `transaction` somewhere down the line.

```
.onInAppPurchaseCompletion { product, result in
    if case .success(.success(let transaction)) = result {
        logger.log("Success")
        // do anything you need to do on your end to complete the transaction
        transaction.finish()
    } else {
        logger.log("Failure")
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not working, but you put me on the right track! We need to use several switch-case structure, until we are deep enough and do call the `transaction.finish()` code.